# expand vector with interpolated values

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have two vectors that happen to be lat and long that I extracted from a shape file. I would like to interpolate the values so I have the same resolution as the points from which I am finding the distance.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365096/matlab-insert-value-in-between/5365382#5365382) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383445/faster-method-of-interpolation-in-matlab) that almost solve my problem.  The difference is I do not know the spacing between my vector points (they vary) and I want to make sure I always have at most 0.0042 deg between points.  Below are the first 10 points of my lat/long vectors.

`latlim=interp1(latlim,1:0.001:numel(latlim));` gets me what I want to avoid any aliasing but I'd like to get exactly 0.0042 between points rather than just 1000 new points for the sake of efficiency. I have a lot of points to iterate on.

```
latlim=[78.1530 77.9963 77.6970 77.4092  77.7322 78.0511 78.1530 NaN 78.8044 78.6020];
latlim=interp1(latlim,1:0.001:numel(latlim));

lonlim=[-111.2644 -109.8545 -110.1869 -112.0512 -113.5343 -112.7246 -111.2644 NaN -110.9637 -109.6631];
lonlim=interp1(lonlim,1:0.001:numel(lonlim));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question:

If you want a constant step of 0.042 then try:

`lonlim = interp1( lonlim, lonlim(1): 0.042 :lonlim(end) );`

This will create a vector starting at the first value of lonlim, which is lonlim(1), with a step of 0.042, until the last value of lonlim, which is lonlim(end).

Hope it works! :)

Comment: I am getting all NaNs in my output with this method. Remove NaNs from original vector and consider a subset:  `lonlim=lonlim(find(isnan(lonlim)));`  `lln=lonlim(1:10)`  `llninterp=interp1(lln,lln(1):0.0042:lln(end));`  `llninterp=interp1(lln,1:0.005:numel(lln));` are all values.